# How to create shared element transition on Android 12 Splashscreen API?

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

Is it possible to create a shared element transition of an iconView from the splashscreen into the main activity? If so, how?

I've looked around but it seems that with previous posts they utilize fragments or two separate activities to create this effect. Am relatively new to Android dev and Kotlin so would very much appreciate some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know for sure so I'm not writing this as a full answer, but to have a shared element transition between a native splash screen and another Activity/Window, you need the second activity to be launched with `makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, View, String)`, which you have no control over for the launcher activity. However, it _might_ be possible to "steal" or re-create the splash screen's ImageView at the same position, and animate it from there.